# How can I remplace html and css in a page depending on the url

Tags: javascript, html, css, url

I have a navigation as such: HOME TRAVEL  MEDIA

travel and media pages have the same layout but not the same elements, the main color and the text should change according to the section we are in.

TRAVEL

main color = @red

text = You are in the travel section

MEDIA

main color = @blue

text = You are in the Media section

How can I dynamically load those elements and change the css depending on the URL ? I am guessing I will have to make an array for each sections and call the variables depending on the URL, but how can I change the CSS ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! we would help you on what you've tried yourself

Comment: I would recommend adding a class in the body to differentiate between the URLs.

Answer (score 0):

You should use javascript to achieve this kind on dynamic changes.
To get a url you can use window.location.href
Then using an "if" statement you can control each page.
For example :

```
if (window.location.href == "http://www.yourwebsite.com/TRAVEL")
    document.getElementById("yourCssElement").classList.add('travel');
```

Same goes for other pages.

Then in css you set the style you want for each class (travel,media etc..)

And that's it, when ever you load a page with the relevant url the corresponding class will be added to your element.